# API-only Rails 6 POST with a chunked response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api

I have a fairly simple Rails 6.0 API-only application serving JSON; I am a little disturbed to find that the response headers to a POST request include "transfer-encoding: chunked", the response body is a few 10s of bytes so this seems inappropriate.

cURL output:

```
> POST /profiles/779397007/activities HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:3000
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 58
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> 
* upload completely sent off: 58 out of 58 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 201 Created
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-Download-Options: noopen
< X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies: none
< Referrer-Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< ETag: W/"caf45e454eded06497865cb8e2938360"
< Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
< X-Request-Id: 4a0953ca-0782-4f72-8240-6edd1fd4cdc3
< X-Runtime: 0.287641
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

Would anyone have any idea why this is happening? (Or just how I can disable it?)  I've tried adding `stream: false` to the call to `#render` in the controller, but that has no effect (the documentation states ":stream only works with templates. Rendering :json or :xml with :stream won't work.".

A similar sounding [problem](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/37423) was found with Rails' request handling, but this is in a Rails response.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to fix this?

Comment: @RyanGlen: I never did, sadly

Comment: I figured it out this morning, try adding the Content length middleware to your development.rb environment.

Comment: @RyanGlen -- I'll give that a go, thanks!